# How to fix my method toString in class worker?

Tags: oop, ocaml

I have some problems with printing types.

For example, define

```
type experience = Beginner | Experienced;;
class worker e = 
object(self)
val exp : experience = e
method toString = let type_printer = function
                      | Beginner -> "Beginner"
                      | Experienced -> "Experienced" in
                  print_string ("Worker with experience " ^ (type_printer exp))
end;;
```

So I want to print the type I defined, among other things. When I called my method, nothing happened. I assume that the problem is in helper function. How to fix it?

Comment: If `exp` isn't mutable, what's the point in using it rather than just using `e`?

Comment: I would also suggest that a `toString` method would be reasonably expected to return a string that can then be printed (_or treated in some other way_).  E.g. `print_string (some_worker#toString)`.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed a typo in your code (print_sting => print_string).

After this change, your code works for me.

```
# (* Enter the above code *)
class worker : experience ->
    object val exp : experience method toString : unit end
# let w0 = new worker Beginner;;
val w0 : worker = <obj>
# w0#toString;;
Worker with experience Beginner- : unit = ()
```

It might help if you show a complete interaction with your code that fails in the way you're seeing.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. It just doesn't print anything, but there is output `- : unit = ()`. I must say that this code I wrote is a very simple simulation of my problem. To make long story short, my problem is in printing the type I made.

Comment: I solved the problem. I have to add `"\n"`: `print_string ("Worker with experience " ^ (type_printer exp)^"\n")`